# Free android plugin of in-app purchase for Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I'm looking for plugin of android in-app purchase for Unity3d. I spent a lot of time for it, but i found only paid plugins. Does somebody know free plugin of android in-app purchase for Unity3d?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this: [**openiab**](http://www.onepf.org/openiab)

It's free, and has support for many stores, including the iOS store.

Comment: How can i add another store to this library? That use same in-app purchase probably.